# DIV position change while scrolling down using scrollTop(); - jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm stuck with this, hope any of you can help me out.

I have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
<body>
```

With this CSS:

```
#one, #two, #three {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var y = $(window).scrollTop();
var one = $('#one').height();
var two = $('#two').scrollTop();
var three = $('#three').scrollTop();

var pos_one = 310;
var pos_two = 454;
var pos_three = 596;

if( y > one ){
    $("#header").fadeIn(200);
} else {
    $('#header').fadeOut(200);
}

if( (y > one) && (y < two) ) {
    $('.bubble').animate({
        "left" : pos_two + "px" 
    }, 300);
}

if( (y > two) && (y < three) ) {
    $('.bubble').animate({
        "left" : pos_three + "px" 
    }, 300);
}
});
```

So, `#header` is fading in when I reach `#two`, that's working. The problem I have is that `.bubble` `div` is not moving when I reach the other sections while scrolling.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have not explained what the desired output should be.

Comment: You should check how many times the scroll event is triggered. Maybe the problem you see is caused by the animation being triggered hundreds of times

Answer (score 0):

simply use `overflow property`

just include overflow:hidden within your css something like this....

```
#one, #two, #three {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

you can use property value as per your need. here is the reference link [overflow property link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Let me know it will help you or not ???

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough on my explanation. What I need is a div (.bubble in the example) to move right inside a menu when I scroll down trough the website's different sections (#one, #two, #three). What it seems to happen is that the one, two, three vars I had set up on my js file are not being updated or something.

Comment: Overflow hidden didn't made any difference :(

Comment: this information is not enough to understand what actually you need. Can you add image of your overall structure or what you need is.