# Using scrollTop() to move a DIV when a DIV with overflow-y:scroll is scrolled

Tags: overflow, scrolltop

Ohai!

I am trying to add a little effect to my menu on my website. Here is the event I want to create :

1- user loads the page: the menu is at 36px away from the top of the page ;

2- user starts scrolling down to read the content ;

3- when the user has scrolled exactly 36px, the menu moves to the very top of the page and stays there ;

4- the user continues scrolling down, the menu is still fixed at the very top ;

5- the user scrolls up until to reach less than 36px to the top, the menu goes back to his first position, 36px away from the top.

It's very funny, I just noticed that Stack Overflow is using some code to do exactly the same to the "**Similar Questions**" box I have on the right of the page when I write my new question. If you want to have an overview, just [start creating a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and watch it. I tried to find out what they are using, but failed.

For my effect, I used the `scrollTop()` jQuery property, associated to the `scroll()` one. Here is the code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 36) {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '0px'});
        } else {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '36px'});
        }
        });
```

This is working for the `document`, which means the entire body of the page.

Now the problem is that I want to use this in an `article` element which have the `overflow-y :scroll` property. When I'm talking about the `<article>` element, I'm refering to the one used in HTML5 documents (such as `<nav>`, `<aside>`, `<section>`, `<footer>` ...).

As result, the JQ does not find any scroll in the `document` and this is true because now, the only scroll in the whole page is inside the `article` element. The body never moves and it's intended.

So I tried this:

```
$('article').scroll(function() {
        if ($('article').scrollTop() >= 36) {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '0px'});
        } else {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '36px'});
        }
        });
```

And also this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 36) {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '0px'});
        } else {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '36px'});
        }
        });
```

And even this:

```
$('#insidecontent').scroll(function() {
        if ($('#insidecontent').scrollTop() >= 36) {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '0px'});
        } else {
        $('#menu').css({'top': '36px'});
        }
        });
```

`#insidecontent` is the name of the `div` which follows the `article` element as you will be able to see later in the code I'll give you by Jsfiddle.net.

And this is not working. Not because of the `article` element, I'm using another jQuery code to dynamically resize the height which is also focusing `article` without any problem. And I tried without it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fKkML/1/

Here you can find the whole code with the first version (`$(document)`) and **without** the `overflow-y: scroll`, to see which effect I'm talking about. It is working, just scroll in the *Result* box.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCuez/7/

And here the version with `overflow-y: scroll` turned on and `$('article')`, which is not working.

Note: in the second link, the overflow is handled the same way by Jsfiddle.net, it seems that this is the whole body which is scrolling. But as you can see, the effect is fucked up anyway. And you can try this code on local on your computer by creating the files, you'll see.

Note 2: I had to add a `margin-top: 70px` to `article` in those demos, but in real and entire code it's not needed.

Note3: I'm a "pro" user of HTML5/CSS3 but **not** of jQuery, this is the first time I do my own JQ code, with the help of the Web. I'm a very noob on this subject, so if you could detail your answer to help me to understand it correctly, I would really thank you.

I've search for an answer here before posting this. For example I found [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990191/div-position-change-while-scrolling-down-using-scrolltop-jquery) a bit related to mine, but not really. I didn't found any which really could help me or would be really the same as mine.

Thank you a lot for the help you may give me. I am open to other ways to get the same result, but this one seems very close to work.

Comment: I changed `height: auto;` of the `article` to `height: 200px;` and it's working. The weird thing is it's working only in JSFiddle.net space. Even if I copy paste every single character of the three boxes into new .html and .css files, it does not work. I don't understand. See the working result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BCuez/10/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

First problem was the `height` which was set to `auto` because I have another JS code which dynamically change its size. The `height` needs to be defined (px, em, %).

Second problem was the missing `window.onload=function(){` at the very beginning. JSFiddle added it by itself, I just had to check the code with F12 in chrome. I added it into my own code, it's working.

Here is the final code you can use by yourself into your own code:

jQuery:

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('article').scroll(function () {
        if ($('article').scrollTop() >= 36) {
            $('#menu').css({
                'top': '0px'
            });
        } else {
            $('#menu').css({
                'top': '36px'
            });
        }
    });
    }
```

CSS :

```
article {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>    <a href="#">
                                Elem1
                            </a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="#">
                                Elem2
                            </a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="#">
                                Elem3
                            </a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="#">
                                Elem4
                            </a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="#">
                                Elem5
                            </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <article>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eleifend neque in sodales iaculis. Suspendisse porta sodales turpis, ut bibendum justo sagittis at. Vivamus ut laoreet tellus. Integer rutrum vel quam in imperdiet. Cras mattis lacus sem, eu suscipit urna adipiscing et. Etiam convallis, tortor ac gravida luctus, nibh tellus porttitor lorem, vel tempus massa purus sed orci. Donec condimentum dolor velit, convallis auctor velit dapibus sed. Integer commodo ullamcorper libero, in pharetra tortor auctor nec. Donec tristique turpis quis felis posuere feugiat. Fusce molestie elementum gravida. Nulla nec quam et metus gravida ornare eget ac elit. Morbi sit amet massa ornare, euismod dolor fringilla, porttitor felis. Sed mattis orci ante, nec sodales enim varius non. Proin velit justo, ultrices vel mollis id, ultrices a nibh. Aenean lacinia ullamcorper leo, sed adipiscing libero vestibulum nec. Phasellus est erat, tincidunt vel mi non, condimentum vestibulum lacus. Quisque placerat id mauris a hendrerit. Phasellus venenatis eros vel leo blandit, non blandit velit imperdiet. Praesent id erat in risus tristique iaculis a eget orci. Quisque pellentesque hendrerit ante vitae tincidunt. Vivamus placerat nisi purus, a tincidunt ligula elementum ut. Integer in arcu elit. Phasellus facilisis orci sit amet sapien egestas imperdiet. Ut quis risus sodales, rutrum libero rhoncus, tincidunt ipsum. Praesent suscipit eros id lacinia bibendum. Donec erat sem, fringilla et pulvinar nec, aliquet euismod mi.
        </article>
    </body>
```

- `article` is the whole content where the `overflow-y: scroll` is set.
- `#menu` is the DIV which the position is changed while scrolling.
- `>= 36` in the 3rd line is the number of px the user needs to scroll before the DIV change its position.
- `0px` in the 5th line is the position of the DIV when the scroll is equal or higher than 36px.
- `36px` in the 9th line is the position of the DIV when the scroll is under 36px.

You can add every CSS rule you want in the jQuery code. For example, I added a line to hide some content in the same event. You can also add the `animate()` event.

Good luck!